# Different database table in one dbml

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to add 3 tables from one database and 1 table from an other database in same dbml file. I want to know if it is possible or i have to create two different dbml files for this?

Comment: creating 2 different dbml files will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, one context represents one database connection. So, as Pratik commented, you need to create two contexts (dbml files).